# How to check if user is logged in with FBSDKLoginKit in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit

When I run the app in `viewDidLoad` I need to check if user was logged in before or not.

```
if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {
    print("1")
    presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
    print("2")
    let button = FBSDKLoginButton()
    button.delegate = self
    button.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "user_friends"]
    view.addSubview(button)
}
```

It always prints `"2"`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Below two methods **must be** implemented in `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```